# Terminal.app equivalent of `xterm -e 'cmd'`

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, window-manager, command-line

With `xterm` (and `gnome-terminal`, `terminator`, etc), you can run the following command:

```
$ xterm -e 'vim somefile.txt'
```

xterm will open and run the specified program (in this case, Vim). When the program exits, the terminal window closes as well. Running the above command, if you were to quit Vim, the terminal would go away as well.

Is there any way to get this (or similar) functionality through Terminal.app (on OSX)? The solution can be in AppleScript, Bash or anything else really, as long as it's achievable via commands I could run in a Bash script.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors .

Comment: That gets me to starting the terminal from the command line, which helps, but I still need to get it to run a program and close the window when that program exits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With AppleScript, you can do:

```
on run argv
    set command to item 1 of argv --you can customize this to be constant
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script (command & "; exit")
    end tell
end run
```

This will open Terminal and tell it to run a command (Your default settings need to close the window when the shell exits). 
To run this, just use `osascript filename.scpt "$command_to_run"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `open` command (`/usr/bin/open`).

For example, say that I want to open  the file test.txt with Textmate and close the shell afterwards. I could use the following command:

```
open -W -a Textmate test.txt && exit
```

- The `-W` option will cause it to wait until Textmate is closed.
- The `-A` option allows you to specify the application

The second part of the command line (`exit`) will not cause the Terminal *application* to quit, but can close the Terminal *window* if you change the default preferences. In the Terminal preferences, click on the *Shell* tab and change the setting *When the shell exits* to *Close the window*

[image: Terminal preferences]

If you really want to exit the Terminal application, you could replace `exit` by a call to a Bash script. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo | osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal"
  quit
end tell
EOF
```

(Source adapted from [Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040623231530448))

This will still cause Terminal to show a popup asking if you want to close the application.

[image: Terminal popup]